# Switch statement with array of enum cases

Tags: swift, enums

I have a an array of enum cases, I wanna run a switch statement on these cases but getting this error: 'Enum case 'North' not found in type [Directions].

```
enum Directions {
  case north
  case west
  case east
  case south

  static let all  = [north, west, east, south]
}

class MyViewController {
    var directions = Directions.all

    func foo () {
        switch directions {
        case .north: // Error here ('Enum case 'North' not found in type '[Directions]')
            print("Going north")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using a array of your enums in the switch statement?

Comment: What you are trying to do is meaningless.  You need to perform the switch on each item in the array not the array as a whole.  For example can you ask this question does [north, west, east, south] equal north?

Comment: This question is more about using an array of enums then what Im using them for. I will ofc do a check for a specific value in my function. So there will be a ex: 

let goingInDirection = .north 

Then func foo (goingInDirection) {
    switch ...
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to loop over the array and then you can use the switch

```
func foo () {
    for direction in directions {
        switch direction {
        case .north: print("Going north")
        case .west: print("Going west")
        case .east: print("Going east")
        case .south: print("Going south")
        }
    }
}
```

> The name of the enum should be singular so `Direction` instead of `Directions`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are comparing a array of Directions type to an Directions enum case. You need to compare a particular element of array as listed below:

```
enum Directions {

    case north
    case south
    case east
    case west
    static let all  = [north, west, east, south]
}


class MyViewController {
    var dir = Directions.all

    func testing(){

        switch dir[0] {
            case .north:
                 print("north")
            default:
                 print("default")
        }
    }
}

var a = MyViewController()

a.testing()

// out put : north
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the mention code in below way

```
enum Directions {
  case north
  case west
  case east
  case south
}

class MyViewController {

    func foo () {
        switch Directions 
      {
        case Directions.north: 
            print("Going north")
        }
    }
}
```